# GitLab CI Runner suddenly very slow

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a successful setup of a GitLab CI project with a private runner. Suddenly, the CI steps take over 4 minutes, instead of 20-25 seconds. I cannot pinpoint the increase in time. Could it be, that somewhere a timeout is being hit? by accessing a folder/network etc? 
My CI project has a simple `gcc` command, nothing fancy at all.

Any thoughts/experiences with this?

Comment: It's rather hard to say what may be happening without output. Maybe the runner is under load?

Comment: Hello, I'm experiencing similar issues, did you had any luck resolving this ?

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps in Gitlab CI are still an open issue ([#22745](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22745)). However you could measure it with `ts` from `moreutils`, in bash you can pipe all the output through it with `exec > >(ts ) 2>&1`. Example for ubuntu image follows:

```
ts:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -qq moreutils
    - exec > >(ts ) 2>&1
  script:
    - > 
        for I in {1..10}; do
          sleep $((RANDOM % 10))s;
          echo $I;
        done
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [gitlab-runner docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-commands).

I assume you are running latest versions, which means **gitlab-runner** instead of **gitlab-multi-runner**.

It seems, that you may have lots of not running runners defined in gitlab-runner.toml which slows your CI/CD workflow a lot.

You can verify that by running `sudo gitlab-runner verify` on your gilab host, if you get anything in red, then there is something wrong.

If so, remove not working images from your gitlab-runner configuration in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` or by using command line -> read [gitlab-runner docs again](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-commands).

Restart gitlab-runner service by `sudo gitlab-runner restart`.

After that gitlab workers should work really fast, without any delays.

We :hearts: gitlab too...

In case you are developing with laravel, we have [CI working repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/chilio/laravel-dusk-ci/)